# Terminar conexão remota ssh

Tags: shell-script, ssh

Tenho o seguinte script que abre uma conexão remota no terminal:

```
xterm -e ssh -t user@IP  -p porta  "cd pasta && bash script.sh && exit ; bash"
```

Como fazer para que a conexão seja terminada e seja fechado o terminal após finalizar a execução do script?

Comment: Se remover a parte '&& exit ; bash' deveria fazer exatamente o que você quer - executar e sair.

Comment: @epx É que peguei esse script na net, obrigado. funcionou!